# Different FetchType on @OneToMany and @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Is it possible to have a lazy fetch in the `@OneToMany` side but eager on the `@ManyToOne` side?

**Parent:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("childVal")
private Set<Child> childList;
```

**Child:**

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private Parent parent;
```

Notice that the `FetchType` is specified differently on the two sides. However, this didn't work and the parent value was not eagerly loaded when only children were retrieved from the DB.

Basically, I would like to load the children in the parent only on request but always load the parent on a child when the child is loaded.

If that is not possible, how can I induce a retrieval of the parent in the child so that it is not null? The corresponding DB value is certainly not null. I tried referencing the instance variable but that didn't fetch the parent.

Comment: Please, add your code where you get a child.

Comment: Note that every 'toMany' association is loaded Lazy by default, and every 'toOne' is loaded eagerly in JPA, so you do not need to specify this behavior in annotation properties. Please post that part of code, where you retrieve entities from DB.